# How to achieve animation effects like(word puzzle game) in iphone application?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, game-center, uiviewanimation, cabasicanimation

i need to achieve an animation effect like (the Effects in "Pic Something","Pic Reveal" and so on) in my app.

What i am saying is i need to implement this tasks

Task1: when the user touches one Letter, then it change its frame(current position) to another frame(target position).

Task2:when the user touch the Letter(in Target position), it comes back to its original position again.

this can be clearly understood if u see the sample Apps.

[image]

I didn't find out any samples on internet also.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `UIView` animation and animation blocks in iOS, that's what you need. With them you can create any animation you like. Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation).

And about the whole system you described - I would create an `NSDictionary` of `UIView` positions and attach those to the corresponding tags of `UIViews`- this way you will always know from which place every `UIView` came from.